# Display only the newest record for each row in MySQL db using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables of which one is updated daily. I would like to display "only" the latest record for each row.

This is the query I am using now that of course returns all the records.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ss_pumps, secondary_systems WHERE ss_pumps.id=secondary_systems.segment_id 
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: how are your tables related with each other?

Comment: the "id" on ss_pumps is the "segment_id" on secondary_systems

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here's what I got:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    ss_pumps ssp
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM secondary_systems ORDER BY id DESC ) ss ON ( ssp.id = ss.segment_id )
GROUP BY
    ssp.id
ORDER BY
    ssp.id ASC
```

> **CAVEAT:** I'm assuming that the `secondary_systems` has its own `id` field that also autoincrements. That's the only way you can make sure you're getting *"only" the latest record for each row*.

---

**Demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f816b/2/0

In my demo `ss_pumps` held the parents while `secondary_systems` held the children. Each parent has 3 children. All but the last children are boys. The last child is always a girl.  According to your problem, the resulting query should yield only girls.

```
| ID | PARENT | SEGMENT_ID | CHILD |
------------------------------------
|  1 | mother |          1 | betty |
|  2 | father |          2 |  tina |
```

Comment: I did not have an auto id in secondary_systems. I added it, and to nobody's surprise but mine IT WORKED!

Comment: be careful with the records return on table `secondary_systems`.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the latest record for every `segment_id` by `ID` using subquery. The result of the subquery is then join against the two tables: `ss_pumps` and `secondary_systems`.

```
SELECT  a.*, c.* 
FROM    ss_pumps a
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  segment_id, MAX(datefield) max_val
            FROM    secondary_systems
            GROUP   BY segment_id
        )b ON a.id = b.segment_id
        INNER JOIN secondary_systems c
            ON  b.segment_id = c.segment_id AND
                b.max_val = c.datefield
```

Actually, I'm not sure how your tables: `ss_pumps` and `secondary_systems` are related with each other.

I think you want it the other ways,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    secondary_systems a
        INNER JOIN ss_pumps b
            ON a.segment_ID = b.segment
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  segment, MAX(ID) max_val
            FROM    ss_pumps
            GROUP   BY segment
        ) c ON  b.segment = c.segment AND
                b.ID = c.max_val
```

Comment: could you not just do a GROUP BY segment_id ORDER BY id ASC on the original query and get the same result?

Comment: No, how about the other columns?

Comment: without knowing what his data is we can't say for sure if the columns have different data or not. but a group by on sub id and a sort on the primary id should bring back the latest from the sub table too once joined.

Comment: @Dave `group by on sub_id and a sort on the primary id should bring back the latest from the sub table` -- are you really sure with that? how about the subtable contains 12 columns and the OP want to get all values from the latest column, do you think it will work?

Comment: ss_pumps fields are ) id | segment | pump | jci secondary_systems fields are ) segment_id | temp | dp | sup | ret | bpass |dis |
oil | mag | vfd | filt

Comment: @user2039676 did you try the query above against your records?

Comment: @JW yes and it returned #1054 - Unknown column 'ID' in 'field list'

Comment: what are the columns in table `ss_pumps` and `secondary_systems`, it should work because you have said that table `secondary_systems` and it contains column `ID` which is autoo_increment.

Comment: This is what it returned - MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0011 sec )

Comment: what is the main table here? if table `ss_pumps` has one-to-many relationship with table `secondary_systems` then how do you know the latest record of table `secondary_systems` for every `segment_id`?

Comment: do you have any dates or id on table secondary_systems which determines the latest row?

Comment: the table secondary_systems now has an auto id (I added one) and it has a date field which is TIMESTAMP

Comment: @JW I don't know thats why I asked :) I assumed since it was an inner join it was a 1-1 relationship not a one to many. You are ofc right if its one to many and he wanted to return all sub table rows he'd either have to double loop/query or do as you've done

Comment: @user2039676 be careful of using implicit use of `GROUP BY` as it leads to invalid rows returned.

Comment: which answer do you prefer now?

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

`SELECT * FROM ss_pumps, secondary_systems WHERE ss_pumps.id=secondary_systems.segment_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

This is assuming that id is an auto increment column and will always be inserted in order.

Comment: Yes it is auto id. The query you post only returns a single record, not the newest one for each row.

Comment: the secondary_systems table does not have an auto increment id